# Unable to drag and drop fragments in android studio

Tags: android, rendering

> Unable to drag and drop fragment in android studio. 
>   It gives rendering problem.

Comment: Android studio still have a long way to go even though it has gone a really long way. Try a latest version and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: @Diode ok. I will do.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from UI portion of the interface builder, you will have much more control when you just implement the screen with XML.  Android Studio (as far as I know) will occasionally show that error.  Usually when you are displaying a fragment with it.  If that is not the case, try a restart to fix.  Tell me the widget you are trying to add and I will see what I can do to help.